# Why Facebook's .setSize() can only increase the height of Canvas app?

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, facebook

I am trying to adjust the height of my Facebook Canvas app after dynamic update of the page content. One is supposed to do this with `FB.Canvas.setSize()` however it only increases the height. The same thing with `.setAutoResize()`. I have posted a workaround on SO, but it is too blinky. Can one improve it somehow?

[How to resize Facebook Canvas app (iFrame) correctly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4695918/how-to-resize-facebook-canvas-app-iframe)

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use the new FB.Canvas.setAutoGrow as the .setAutoResize() is deprecated.  See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Canvas.setAutoGrow/